# Text Frame List

Tags: python, recursion

The use will give an input with several items where each item is seperated by a space. Example of input:

```
   star jupiter sun
```

Then the output will be

```
***********
* star    * 
* jupiter *
* sun     *
***********
```

The length of `*` depends on the longest word from the list where there should be a space after the last alphabet. The problem with my code is I have a fixed length of `*` which is not dependent on the length of the longest word. The `*` from the right hand side of the shorter word is not consistent with the above output as well. I have an idea of using print(("*")* the length of the random longest word) but I am not sure whether it is possible or not. This is my code

```
s = str(input("Please enter a list of items seperated by a space:"))
print("*")

for word in s.split():
    print("* " + word + " *")

print("*")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the star length by using this one-liner

```
star_length = max(map(len, s.split())) + 2
```

which will set `star_length` to the length of the longest word plus 2. You can then output it like this

```
print('*' * star_length)
for i in s.split():
    print('* ' + i + (' ' * (star_length - len(i))) + ' *')
print('*' * star_length)
```

Comment: `print('* {}{} *'.format(i, ' '*(star_length - len(i))))` is much more readable

Comment: If my input is seperated by coma instead of space, it is possible for me to get the same output? The coma should not be in the output

Comment: @user7043763 Pretty much, but instead of `s.split()`, you'd want `s.split(',')`.

Comment: What is the map function?

Comment: map(A, B) will return B but with every item of B having been applied to A. Basically, `map(q, ["a", "b", "c"])` returns `[q("a"), q("b"), q("c")]`.

Comment: @user7043763 The `map` function applies a method to every element in a list (or other iterable).

Answer (score 1):

To find the longest word, you will want to use

`max(listOfWords, key=lambda arg: len(arg))`

This `max` function finds the largest word in the list, and `key=FUNCTION` will be used to sort it. Here, the function returns the length of its argument, so it will sort it by the length. `max` looks for the biggest value.

Now, you will want to enclose that in a `len()` to find out the length`and add 2 to see how many stars you should put at the top and bottom. You can multiply strings by numbers, for example`
"abc" * 3`will give`abcabcabc`.

If you want to multiply the `*` characters, then you will probably want to do this

`print("*" * (len(max(listOfWords, key=lambda arg: len(arg))) + 2))`

Remember that multiplication, even with strings, binds tighter than addition, so we must use brackets.

The next part we need to pad the end of the line with spaces, using a similar method. We want to subtract the words length from the longest word's length to get the amount of spaces we need to pad with.

`print("* " + word + (len(word) - (len(max(listOfWords, key=lambda arg: len(arg))) + 2)) * " " + " *")`

The final line is the same as the first. Now here is the full code:

```
s = str(input("Please enter a list of items seperated by a space:"))

print("*" * (len(max(listOfWords, key=lambda arg: len(arg))) + 2))

for word in listOfWords:
    print("* " + word + (len(word) - (len(max(listOfWords, key=lambda arg: len(arg))) + 2)) * " " + " *")

print("*" * (len(max(listOfWords, key=lambda arg: len(arg))) + 2))
```

This code is quite confusing so I may have made a mistake.

Comment: You're better off using `max(map(len, listOfWord))` instead of using `max` with a key argument because the words themselves don't actually matter in this case but just the length.

Comment: @EliSadoff good idea, however I have never understood the `map` function in Python - it doesn't return a list like I expect

Comment: In python 2 it returns a list, whereas in python 3 it returns a mappable object. This is because python 3 has lazy iteration which means that if you want to apply a function to the resultant object that doesn't require full mapping, it won't map fully. If you want a list from map in python 3, you can just use `list(map(...))`

Comment: @EliSadoff Thanks so much! That helped loads!

Comment: No worries, python is a really interesting language. I've learned so much from other users on SO. If you stay active here, you'll really get to learn a ton about the language.